# Correct autocorrelation when using reg3 in Stata

Tags: time-series, stata

I'm running a simultaneous equation model (three equations) on a time series dataset using `reg3` in Stata.

Some colleagues are concerned that the problem of autocorrelation may be present.

After running `reg3`, I used [lmareg3](http://www.haghish.com/statistics/stata-blog/stata-programming/download/lmareg3.html) to test autocorrelation and obtained the following results,

[image]

My questions are 1) does the above result suggest that autocorrelation is present? 2) how to correct autocorrelation when using `reg3` (like `vce(robust)` when using `xtreg`)?

Comment: This question is not about programming and should be posted on Cross Validated instead. Also, you have been around long enough to know that screenshots are not helpful. I think it would be a good idea for you to read again [ask] and [mcve]. `help dataex` will also help with the latter.